# Making Functions Public from Inside jQuery Function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a block of JavaScript/jQuery that works fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
         function doSomething() {
             // Do something amazing here!
         }
        // Many various jQuery handlers and support functions
    });
</script>
```

But now I'd like my `doSomething()` function to be callable from another block of script on the same page.

I understand I can do that by moving `doSomething()` outside of the jQuery function (`$(function () {})`). But then `doSomething()` wouldn't be able to call the helper functions inside of the jQuery function.

I could move the other functions outside of the jQuery function, but some of them are handlers that need to be initialized, and they share they same helper functions.

Is there a way to keep all my functions inside my jQuery function, but just make one of them visible outside of it?

And any suggestions on where I could go to read up on this?

Comment: "I'd like my...function to be callable from another block of script on the same page". Why do you want to do that?

Comment: @AlexW: Because this is a huge WebForms project with hundreds of components, and some of those components need to interact with other ones at the client level.

Comment: Why define any functions inside `$(function () { ... });`? I don't see any reason why you would need to do this. I would just put them all outside.

Comment: Johnatha, i will advice you to invest your time to learning RequireJS, it's will help you to bring modularity to your code and some other improvements to project

Comment: @LeshaOgonkov: Thanks but I'm more interested in learning about JavaScript and jQuery before taking on new technologies.

Comment: If you're writing a lot of code, following a certain pattern sure helps. I tend to stick to different variations of literals, something like this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/4zhzqz0u/**

Comment: @adeneo: Yes, this is where I'm weak. However, I've been doing a lot of JSON lately, and your jsfiddle makes a little more sense to me. Your code doesn't really help me as far as setting up jQuery handlers. But perhaps I can just design my object with an interface for the handlers outside of the object to use.

Comment: It's just an example of using literals, here's another one -> **http://jsfiddle.net/4zhzqz0u/1/**, I find it easier to structure and find things when there's a lot of code, and it fits well with jQuery. For plugins and other things, I often use prototyping or whatever fits, but still always a pattern that's easy to follow, at least when you get used to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript has functional scope. So, the reason you can't call your function if it is nested within

```
$(function () { ... });
```

is because it is only accessible within that function's scope.

You can easily move that *function definition*:

```
function doSomething() { ... }
```

outside of the `$(function(){...})` function and still have access to variables within the `$(function(){...})` function's scope by passing the variables as parameters to the function and then having it return any modifications:

```
    $(function () {
         var blah = 'blah';
         var result;
         result = doSomething(blah);
         // Many various jQuery handlers and support functions
     });
     function doSomething(blah) {
         // Do something amazing here!
         return newBlah;
     }
     // Now you can call your doSomething function in the global scope too
     var example = "test";
     var result = doSomething(example);
```

Comment: Maybe I can restructure it this way. I know there are ways to be more OOP with JavaScript and that's where my knowledge is lacking. I was hoping for something more along those lines, but perhaps this is the best answer to my current task.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in fact you **should** move your logic from this wrapper.

It's intended for initialization of logic that should run after DOM is ready. You shouldn't make any functions here.

Consider following pattern for your code:

```
(function($) {
  // Your logic here
  // You could safely export your functions to
  // global scope from here, if you really need
  var app;

  app = {
    forms: doSomething
  };

  function doSomething() {
    // Do something amazing here!
  }

  window.app = app; 

  $(function() {/* start interact with DOM */});
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: If you haven't figured it out already, my background is in languages other than javascript. So your first suggestion doesn't provide me with any new or helpful information. Yes, I could consider the pattern you suggest. But as it stands, I have no idea why I should. In fact, I don't even understand what it does.

Comment: My second sentence about why it should be done. In short: you don't need to wait for DOM, to initialize your logic code

Answer (score 0):

You can do it extending jQuery:

```
$.extend({
    foo: new function () {
        var _self = this;            

        _self.doSomething = function () {

        };   

        _self.initialize = function () {
            $('#button-x').click(function(){
                _self.doSomething(); //use the function inside
            }); 
        }; 
});

$(function () {
    $.foo.initialize();
    $.foo.doSomething(); //use the function outside
});
```